# Strings from DBF to Visual Studio with Encoding

Tags: vb.net, dbf

I am not sure I have reassumed well my issue in the title, but I am doing an app with Visual Studio in VB.net. I should import some strings from a DBF file. I have already set a connection and successfully read the strings from the DBF.
The DBF file has two columns: the first with native language (Italian) and the second with local language (for example Russian). The DBF is firstly used by Citect Scada program for multilingual interface.
What I am trying to do is:
- open the DBF file
- search for a string in Italian
- get the correspondent string in Russian
- place the string in a label
When I'm trying to get the string in Russian, in visual studio I always see strange characters.
I have made some researches on Google, but I cannot figure out how to change encoding while getting the string in Russian. 
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding

Comment: Also this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture?view=netcore-3.1